# Hiding section of resume when printing traditional view resume

Tags: feature-request, bug, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story, traditional-view

In past, the feature for printing tradition resume had option to hide certain sections from the final output. Since the recent update and move towards developer story, I can't seem to find this option any more. Is it just me or have we lost it?

I think it was a useful feature to hide certain sections from the printed CV because it makes it possible for you to fit your resume to a couple of pages by removing sections which don't need to be present in the printed CV.

Also, I am disappointed to see that we can only edit CV in Developer story mode and not in Traditional mode. Why have you remove useful features from the site? it makes it more difficult to use and I am pondering not use this feature at all but I kind of loved the format that was generated by printing the traditional view CV.

Comment: I don't know anyone who finds the developer story useful.  Get rid of ASAP.

Comment: As someone who keeps a PDF of their resume up to date from time to time, I've had to manually rebuild my PDF version since I can no longer generate it from my SO Careers profile. Also, this is definitely a duplicate.

Comment: I don't think it is an exact duplicate. That question is requesting new features in "Developer story" but here I am requesting existing features back in the "Traditional view". Anyway I don't mind it as long as any of these question help get back the good features in the "Traditional view".